# System.NotSupportedException: Unable to find the default constructor. Please provide the missing constructor (xamarin C#)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an activity which actually calls a fragment to display its content in recyclerView. And the problem is, in some activity, when screen rotation changes, it calls again the OnCreate which is actually right. But I don't know why the base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); gives me the error as the title speak. on other activity which has the same function it goes well. 3/6 activity failed to respond on screen rotation. any knowledge about it?

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); // error occurred here

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.mylayout);
        //rest of codes
    }

    //rest of the codes are removed due to error is only on this part
```

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION:**

when fragment is created with a user-defined constructor, default constructor should also be provided manually even there is nothing inside.

I found out that the problem doesn't exist in base.OnCreate rather in my fragment that I created. I made a fragment with a constructor but I didn't provide a default constructor since it should be coded manually if you created any type of constructor.

I just created a default constructor for it and it solved the problem.